# LED "Underdrive"

Tags: led, voltage, resistors, current

Is there any possible way I could've messed up this LED? I just found a bi-colored flashing LED this morning and I hooked up different voltages on it in the following order:

- 3.7V
- 3.8V
- 4.5V

However, the LED did not light up anyhow, and I'm thinking if it's because the power is too low, or it's because I didn't use a resistor. Will it light up again, or did I kill it? I would appreciate any comments and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, I know it's self-bi-colored because I took it out of a smashed Christmas toy I found at Old Time Pottery and it has 2 pins. Will it light up again? Please help me because I don't like wasting stuff. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Yes, it's rare... and expensive at RadioShack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LEDs should be driven with current, not voltage.  Use a 5V source with 1 kΩ in series with it.  Most LEDs can take at least 5V reverse voltage and the few mA that will flow thru the resistor, but that should be enough to light them visibly indoors.

Unfortunately you provided little useful information about the LED.  How do you know it's bi-color, and do you really mean the LED itself will flash when the appropriate power is applied?  Those exist, but are rare.  Or do you mean by "flashing" that you plan on having the circuit perform the flashing?  If you know so much about the LED, then why not just look up its datasheet?  Does it have 2, 3, or even 4 pins?

If it is truly self-flashing (again, possible but unlikely), then there is some active circuitry in it and treating it like a bare LED may not make it do anything useful.  It could want 3.3V or 5V, with the proper polarity of course, to operate.

Answer the questions above, try all possible combinations of pins with the 5V 1kΩ test in both polarities and report back.

Also consider that LEDs are cheap and plentiful.  You could just get a few that do what you want and forget about this unknown unit.

### Added:

Now that you say the LED has only two pins and you're sure it's bi-color, then the two LEDs inside must be connected back to back.  In that case, the 5V and 1 kΩ test should light up one color with one polarity and the other color with the other polarity.  If you get nothing in either direction, then the LED is fried.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Olin! I just want to ask you one question: Are LEDs that easy to fry? I didn't touch the LED yet, but I would like to know if they are really that sensitive, because I might be using variable voltages for my other ones.

Comment: @Francis: LEDs are usually rather forgiving.  You can usually run a few times their maximum rated current thru them for a while (a few seconds at least) before they go poof.  However, you applied a fixed *voltage*.  That can allow arbitrarily large current to flow.  Still, I would have expected at least a brief and bright flash of light.  You did say this was from a "smashed" toy, so maybe the LED was already broken before you got to it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The LED was still intact and working when I found it and it's wires exposed from the toy, so that's when I got the idea of giving it a new home. Also, please check out my other questions in the near future too. Thanks!

Comment: @Francis: Then maybe this is some kind of integrated unit with more than two back to back LEDs.  You never did answer the question about why you think this is a "flashing" LED.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you didn't use a resistor the LED should have lit up. In overcurrent conditions when the current isn't very strong, the LED won't just die. Instead it will at first start shining brightly and over time change its characteristics. The color of the LED will change too. Only after some time will the LED actually stop conducting current.

If it didn't turn on, then try figuring out which connector is which. If you connect it in reverse, it of course won't work.

SO if you don't have a resistor, try experimenting with lower voltages. The LED should lit up even when there's very low current going through it.

Another thing that could be important is the color of the LED, because it will determine forward voltage drop. You can take a look at [this](http://www.oksolar.com/led/led_color_chart.htm) chart to see some common forward voltages and current limits.

Comment: In my experience, over-volting an LED by a large amount (eg: putting a red LED across a 9V battery) will turn them into small bullets and the top dome can travel some distance! I hasten to add that this happened by accident when I was told a batch of LEDs included internal current limiting resistors to run off 12V - they evidently didn't!

Comment: @Linker3000 That's why I noted the "current isn't very strong" part. Care definitely needs to be taken.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Thanks for the answer. I have tried both pins of the LED when I was messing with it, but it still didn't turn on. I will try using lower voltages for the LED.